# Fixed IP address for service behind aws application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

our company just moved to a new office and therefore also got new network equipment. Es it turns out, our new firewall does not allow pushing routes over VPN that it first has to look up ip addresses for.

As we all know, amazon aws does not allow static ip addresses for its application load balancer.

So our idea was to simply put a network load balancer in front of the application load balancer (there is a pretty hacky way described by aws itself (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/) that seemed to work fine (even if I don't really like the approach with the lambda script registering and deregistering targets)

So here is our problem: as it turns out, the application load balancer only gets to see the network load balancers ip address. This prevents us to use security groups for ip whitelisting which we do quite heavily. On top of that some of our applications (Nginx/PHP based) also do ip address verification and the alb used to pass the clients ip address as an x-forwarded-for header. Now our application only sees the one from the nlb.

We know of the possibility to use the global accelerator but that is a heavy investment as we don't really need what the GA is trying to solve.

So how did you guys solve this problem ?

Thankful for any help :)

Greetings

Comment: Is running NLB + ALB as you do now, much cheaper then running GA with ALB?

Comment: so what you decide finally? I am also having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list of AWS IP addresses for the region your ALB is located, and allow for them in your firewall. They do publish the list and you can filter through it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

I haven't done this myself and I'm unsure if the addresses for ALB are included under the EC2 category of you would take the whole of AMAZON service "to be safe".

Comment: Thanks, but this is not about whitelisting.
Our firewall in the office is our VPN gateway and we need to push push certain routes to our people working in home office.
We restrict some services to be accessed only from our office IP addresses but our VPN gateway does not support pushing dynamic IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand on this? "We know of the possibility to use the global accelerator but that is a heavy investment as we don't really need what the GA is trying to solve."
GA should give you better, more consistent performance, especially if your office is far away from the AWS Region where the ALB is running

Comment: Indeed, but performance is not an issue here and our chosen AWS region is just 200-300 km away from our office (of course routing can sometimes take crazy paths).

This is really just about static ip addresses

Comment: Got it. Out of curiosity what would be the cost if you used GA? It should be $0.015/GB in US/EU or $0.01/GB in Asia Pacific (with some exceptions), and you pay only for the dominant direction (so if you do 49GB inbound to the AWS Region and 51GB outbound, you pay only for the 51GB outbound).